# PHP Amazon AWS S3 - Upload object using Pre-Signed URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to generate a URL that other system can use to upload a file to my S3 bucket. I looked over the documentation and similar issues, however, I cannot find the right solution.

I have tried creating the PreSigned URL multiple ways (`$this->s3` is a reference so S3Client):

1:

```
       $signedUrl = $this->s3->getCommand(
            'PutObject',
            array(
                'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
                'Key' => 'recording_test.mp3',
                'Body' => ''
            )
        )->createPresignedUrl('+2 hours');
```

2:

```
    $command = $this->s3->getCommand('PutObject', array('Bucket' => $this->bucket, 'Key' => 'recording_test3.mp3', 'Body' => ''));

    $request = $command->prepare();

    $signedUrl = $this->s3->createPresignedUrl($request, '+2 hours');
```

When trying to simply access the URL I get following error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

I have also tried it this way:
        $key = 'recording_test2.mp3';
        $url = $this->bucket.'/'.$key;

```
    $request = $this->s3->put($url);

    $signedUrl = $this->s3->createPresignedUrl($request, '+2 hours');
```

However, this generates a URL in format of `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key...`, which yields an error about invalid endpoint, and that endpoint in format `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key...` should be used. Manually changing the URL gives the same invalid signature error as per above.

I cannot see what am I doing wrong or any other way to generate the PreSigned URL?

Thanks for help

Comment: Also, in the error details, there is `StringToSign` field, which is different depending if I just open the URL, or I use it in a form with file upload - not sure if that has to do with anything? If so, how can I make sure the URL is good for uploading a file to the bucket?

Comment: not sure if you you still have same issue, but you should access the link with a put request, not get or post method

Answer (score 0):

When creating your signed URL, you should not use the `Body` key. The signed URL generated includes a signature of the body to be uploaded. Then, when you try upload a file using the URL, it can't match the empty string you are using to the content of the file.

Also, if you are using Curl to put the file, I recommend using \CURLFile, and remember to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");` for your PUT request.